# placing a button location value in a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, location

I'm trying to save a button's location in a variable, but I have no idea how to do it.Since the code shows the x and the y of the button, can I also save both x and y separately?

```
  Console.WriteLine(button.Location);
<X=100,Y=100>
```

I want it to save the X value in var1, and Y value in var2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can save it as a single `Point` or as two different integers:

```
Point location = button.Location;
int xLocation = button.Location.X;
int yLocation = button.Location.Y;
```

You can then restore the position like this:

```
button.Location = location;
button.Location = new Point(xLocation, yLocation);
```

**Note:** `Point` is a `struct` (value type) so changing `location` will *not* change `button.Location`. In other words this will have no effect:

```
Point location = button.Location;
location.X += 100;
```

You'd need to do this:

```
Point location = button.Location;
location.X += 100;
button.Location = location;
```

or

```
button.Location = new Point(button.Location.X + 100, button.Location.Y);
```

Answer (score 2):

`button.Location.X` will give you the X value. `button.Location.Y` will give you the Y value.

So, yes you can save them separately.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Point loc = new Point(button.Location.X,button.Location.Y)
```